# Implementation of DFS algorithm as described by Algorithms - Dasgupta, Papadimitrious, Umesh Vazirani

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I just want feedback regarding C++ coding style and if in any way I can optimize my code (e.g. to use a different data structure). I'm only trying to use up to C++ 14 standard code. Any other improvements are greatly appreciated as well.

file: graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct Edge
{
    char src, dest;
};

class Graph
{
public:

    std::map<char, std::vector<char>> adjList_;

    // marks which nodes have been visited. True = visited, false = not visited
    std::map<char, bool> visited_;
    
    // Graph Constructor
    Graph(std::vector<Edge> const &edges);

    void DFS(Graph& g);

    void explore(Graph& g, char vertex);

    void previst(char vertex);
    
    void postvist(char vertex);
};

inline void printGraph(Graph const &graph)
{
    std::cout << "Printing out the graph \n";
    for(const auto& value : graph.adjList_)
    {
        std::cout << "Source node: " << value.first << " \nconnected elements: " << std::endl;
        
        for(const auto& element: value.second)
        {
            std::cout << element << " ";
        }

        std::cout <<"\n" << std::endl;
    }

}

#endif //GRAPH_H
```

file: graph.cpp

```
#include "graph.h"

Graph::Graph(std::vector<Edge> const &edges)
{
    // add edges to the directed graph
    for (auto &edge: edges)
    {
        // insert at the end
        adjList_[edge.src].push_back(edge.dest);
        
        // establish initial visited values for each node
        visited_[edge.src] = false;
    }
}

void Graph::DFS(Graph& g)
{
    // We check for nodes that have not been visited
    for (auto const& x : g.visited_)
    {
        if (x.second == false)
        {
            explore(g, x.first);
        }
    }
}

void Graph::explore(Graph& g, char vertex)
{
    g.visited_[vertex] = true;
    previst(vertex);


    for(auto const& sourceNode : g.adjList_[vertex])
    {
        if(g.visited_[sourceNode] == false)
        {
            explore(g, sourceNode);
        }
    }
    postvist(vertex);
}

void Graph::previst(char vertex)
{
    std::cout << "Pre visiting vertex: " << vertex << std::endl;
}

void Graph::postvist(char vertex)
{
    std::cout << "Post visting vertex: " << vertex << std::endl;
}
```

file: dfsDriver.cpp

```
#include "../graph.h"

int main()
{
    // undirected edges
    std::vector<Edge> edges = 
    {
        {'g', 'd'}, {'g','h'} , {'d', 'h'},
        {'d', 'g'}, {'h', 'g'}, {'h', 'd'},
        {'d', 'a'}, {'a', 'd'}, {'a', 'b'},
        {'b', 'a'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'c', 'a'},
        {'c', 'f'}, {'f', 'c'},
        {'b', 'f'}, {'f', 'b'}, {'b', 'e'},
        {'e', 'b'}, {'e', 'i'}, {'i', 'e'},
        {'e', 'j'}, {'j', 'e'},
        {'i', 'j'}, {'j', 'i'}, {'k', 'l'},
        {'l', 'k'}
    };

    Graph graph(edges);
    //printGraph(graph);

    graph.DFS(graph);
}
```

input graph:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Optimizing the data structures

You can indeed optimize the way you store the graph a bit. You don't care about the exact order of the vertices, so it is better to use [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of `std::map`, as lookups and insertions will then be \$O(1)\$ instead of \$O(\log V)\$.

For `visited_`, I see two alternatives. First, instead of adding all vertices to it, only add the vertices that have been visited. The `bool` is then unnecessary, and in fact you should then use [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead of a map. Alternatively, store all the data related to a node together in a `struct`, and just have a single container. For example:

```
struct NodeData {
    std::vector<char> neighbors;
    bool visited;
};

std::map<char, NodeData> adjList_;
```

The approach you have taken is the right one *in general*. If you have more information about the graph, for example if it has only a few vertices or very many, or whether it is very sparse or very dense, you might be able to get more performance using more specialized data structures. In fact, since you have limited yourself to `char`s, you could store the graph like so:

```
constexpr std::size_t N = 1 << CHAR_BIT; // most likely 256 on your machine
std::bitset<N> vertices_;
std::array<std::bitset<N>, N> adjList_;
std::bitset<N> visited_;
```

A [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) of 256 bits only uses 32 bytes. Each bit represents whether a vertex is part of the graph (`vertices_`), whether it was visited (`visited_`), or for a given vertex, which vertices are its neighbors (`adjList_`). Consider that an empty `std::vector` uses a similar amount of memory, and `std::map` and friends have to allocate memory for every element they store. The bitsets and the array use a fixed amount of memory, but everything is guaranteed to be stored compactly in memory, and lookups are very fast.

## You can nest structs and classes

It can make sense here to move `struct Edge` into `class Graph`. This avoids polluting the global namespace, and has some other benefits you'll see below.

```
class Graph{
public:
    struct Edge
    {
         char src, dest;
    };
    …
    Graph(std::vector<Edge> const &edges);
    …
};
…
int main()
{
    std::vector<Graph::Edge> edges = {…};
    …
}
```

## No need to pass an object to its own member functions

Why does `Graph::DFS()` take a `Graph&` as a parameter? Since it is a member function of `Graph`, this is unnecessary. The same goes for `Graph::explore()`. You can just write:

```
void Graph::DFS()
{
    for (auto const& x : visited_)
    {
        if (x.second == false)
        {
            explore(x.first);
        }
    }
}
```

## Make the code more generic

You have hardcoded the type of vertex to `char`. What if you have a graph with more than 256 different vertices? Maybe you want to identify vertices by integers, or maybe even strings. You can make your code more generic by using templates:

```
template<typename VertexID>
class Graph
{
public:
    struct Edge
    {
        VertexID src, dest;
    };
    …
    void explore(VertexID vertex);
    void previst(VertexID vertex);
    void postvist(VertexID vertex);
};
```

You can go further. Consider your constructor: it takes a reference to a `std::vector`, but does it really matter what type the container is? What if the caller has the edges in a `std::array`? Converting it to a `std::vector` would be wasteful. You could make your constructor a template that takes any kind of container:

```
template<typename Container>
Graph::Graph(Container const& edges)
{
    for (auto &edge: edges)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

If you accidentily call the constructor with something that is not a container of `Edge`s, this will fail to compile, but probably with some cryptic error messages. With C++20 you can use concepts to restrict the type of container:

```
template<std::ranges::input_range<Edge> Container>
Graph::Graph(Container const& edges)
{
    …
}
```

You also hardcoded `previst()` and `postvist()`. You could make `DFS()` take a function as an argument that it runs on vertices, either using [`std::function<void(VertexID&)>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), or with a template parameter:

```
template<typename Function>
void Graph::DFS(Function& postvisit) {
    for (auto const& x : g.visited_)
    {
        if (x.second == false)
        {
            explore(x.first, postvisit);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Function>
void Graph::explore(VertexID vertex, Function& postvisit)
{
    g.visited_[vertex] = true;

    for(auto const& sourceNode : g.adjList_[vertex])
    {
        if(!g.visited_[sourceNode])
        {
            explore(sourceNode, postvisit);
        }
    }

    std::invoke(postvisit, vertex);
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
std::vector<Graph::Edge<char>> edges = {…};
Graph graph(edges);
graph.DFS([](char vertex) {
    std::cout << "Post visiting vertex: " << vertex << '\n';
});
```

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://questions); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary, and has a negative impact on performance.

## What if you want to call `DFS()` more than once?

If you call `DFS()` a second time, nothing will happen since `visited_` is `true` for all vertices. You should clear `visited_` at the start of `DFS()`. Maybe it is even better not to have `visited_` as a member variable, but instead make it a local variable in `DFS()`, and pass a reference to it to `explore()`. This way, each call to `DFS()` will have a fresh version, and less space is used for the `Graph` object itself.

If you really intend this to be used only once, then this shouldn't be a `class` to begin with. Instead, you could write a free function `DFS()` that takes a set of edges (and possibly a visitor function) as a parameter, and creates all the state necessary for the depth-first search as local variables.